# input of while loop to come from output of `command`

Tags: shell, loops, while-loop

```
#I used to have this, but I don't want to write to the disk
#
pcap="somefile.pcap"
tcpdump -n -r $pcap > all.txt
while read line; do  
  ARRAY[$c]="$line"
  c=$((c+1))  
done < all.txt
```

The following fails to work.

```
# I would prefer something like...
#
pcap="somefile.pcap"
while read line; do  
  ARRAY[$c]="$line"
  c=$((c+1))  
done < $( tcpdump -n -r "$pcap" )
```

Too few results on Google (doesn't understand what I want to find :(  ). I'd like to keep it Bourne-compatible (/bin/sh), but it doesn't *have* to be.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is `sh`-compatible:

```
tcpdump -n -r "$pcap" | while read line; do  
  # something
done
```

However, `sh` does not have arrays, so you can't have your code like it is in `sh`. Others are correct in saying both `bash` and `perl` are nowadays rather widespread, and you can mostly count on their being available on non-ancient systems.

**UPDATE** to reflect @Dennis's comment

Comment: I had high hopes for this one, but it doesn't generate the HTML files! I can't understand why. >>http://stackoverflow.pastebin.com/TecWxMwW

Comment: eek, I left an "echo" inside, that I used for testing. Fixed now, should be equivalent to yours. (BTW, I assume you meant your code does not generate HTML when you insert this snippet - this snippet by itself doesn't generate HTML any more than your snippet did)

Comment: Except that the Bourne shell doesn't have arrays. And, in Bash the two lines in the body of your loop (OK, the OP's loop) can be collapsed into: `ARRAY[$c]+=("$line")` or `ARRAY[c++]="$line"`. But +1 for the pipe into `while`.

Comment: Note that since this uses pipes, any variables created inside the while loop won't be available once the while loop exists (because pipes create a subshell). If you're okay with something that only works in bash, you could feed in the input using [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983261/6157047).

Answer (score 31):

This works in bash:

```
while read line; do  
  ARRAY[$c]="$line"
  c=$((c+1))  
done < <(tcpdump -n -r "$pcap")
```

Comment: Yes. It works in Bash. Any reason why it won't run in /bin/sh? I *would* like to make the script portable. Is portability usually important? To ensure others can also run the script...

Comment: The `<(...)` process substitution syntax is not available to sh.

Comment: Arrays are also not available to sh. But +1 for the process substitution.

Comment: @DW. Didn't know array's aren't supported in `sh`. That doesn't bode well.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about being bourne, you can switch to Perl:

```
my $pcap="somefile.pcap";
my $counter = 0;
open(TCPDUMP,"tcpdump -n -r $pcap|") || die "Can not open pipe: $!\n";
while (<TCPDUMP>) {
    # At this point, $_ points to next line of output
    chomp; # Eat newline at the end
    $array[$counter++] = $_;
}
```

Or in shell, use `for`:

```
for line in $(tcpdump -n -r $pcap)  
do  
 command  
done
```

Comment: In the shell version, you need to set IFS to a only a newline so that the output of `tcpdump` is not broken at each space.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in $(tcpdump -n -r $pcap)  
do  
 command  
done
```

This isn't exactly doing what I need. But it is close. And Shell compatible. I'm creating HTML tables from the tcpdump output. The `for` loop makes a new <tr> row for each word. It should make a new row for each *line* (\n ending).
[Paste bin script01.sh](http://stackoverflow.pastebin.com/TecWxMwW).

Comment: You'll need to do `saveIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; your-for-loop; IFS=$saveIFS` since `IFS` causes things to be broken on spaces, tabs and newlines by default.

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)