# how to get output from `ps` line by line in shell

Tags: linux, shell, sh, ps

I want to list a process with its infos through ps in shell.
Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for line in `ps aux| grep test.py`
do
    echo $line
done
```

But output is:

```
hey
13241
0.0
0.3
48388
13528
pts/18
S+
18:50
0:00
python
test.py
hey
13370
0.0
0.0
14504
1016
pts/21
S+
19:00
0:00
grep
test.py
```

It divide the line into many parts, but I want I can get one line information about the process which name is test.py like command in terminal:

```
hey   13241  0.0  0.3  48388 13528 pts/18   S+   18:50   0:00 python test.py
hey   13446  0.0  0.0  14504   976 pts/21   S+   19:08   0:00 grep --color=auto test.py
```

how to solve that

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Nothing about this is specific to `ps` -- answers about how to iterate over input from other sources line-by-line are every bit as valid.

Comment: (That said, in general, you shouldn't be using output from `ps` in your scripts if you can avoid it. For most uses `pgrep` is more appropriate, or using an approach such as advisory locking that doesn't require reading the process table at all to check if a program is running).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` command will read one line from standard input and place it into a variable for you. It'll exit with status 1 when it reaches the end of input, which you can use to end a while loop:

```
ps aux | grep test.py | while read line; do
  echo LINE:
  echo "$line"
  echo
done
```

If you want it to, `read` will split the input into separate variables using the internal field separator (IFS), and if the input has more fields than variables, it'll stop splitting when it gets to your last variable and just put the remainder of the line, unsplit, in there.

Which means that if you supply just one variable (I called it "line" in the example above), you'll get the whole line, unsplit, and you won't need to worry about setting IFS.

Answer (score 2):

Based on melpomene's comment, this should work for you while [keeping compatibility to sh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983416/344480).

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux | grep test.py | while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

Comment: `grep 1`? What's the point of that?

Comment: If your goal is to skip the header, `ps auxw | { read; while read ...; done; }` -- that way you avoid putting overhead into the process used to read 100% of the lines when you only want to avoid the first.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This was for testing purposes only and I corrected that. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Matthias what is the IFS work for?

Comment: @code_worker It makes sure that you read the whole line, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/90304