# Visual Studio Code: Issue in reading folder path with spaces in the name

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I am trying to run a bash script in Visual Studio Code using the bash shell.
What I'am trying to do is to read a `.csv` file within a directory `"OneDrive - research institution project/files"` using `sed 1d $p_path$csv_name | while IFS=, read -r gcm xml_nm xml_m co2con batchy`.

Besides the scripting for reading the .csv file, which works because it has been already used, everytime I run it for my folder I get problems due to the blank spaces in the folder path.

I already tried to use `\`, and both double and single quotes (
`p_path = "OneDrive\ -\ research\ institution\ project/files"` or
`p_path = 'OneDrive - research institution project'/files` or
`p_path = "OneDrive - research institution project/files"`

but nothing worked so far, returning always errors like:
`sed: unknown option -- \`
Assuming that I cannot change the name of the directory, is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: "_I already tried to use \, and both double and single quotes but_" show _exactly_ what you tried. There is a non-zero chance you just did it wrong and if you don't show what you tried, nobody will know whether that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not have to escape the spaces, if the variables are used correctly (see [`shellcheck.net`](https://www.shellcheck.net) for confirmation):

```
sed 1d "${p_path}${csv_name}"
```

Then there is the `while`, which seems to be missing a `do/done`.

If you want the [input of while loop to come from output of `command`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2983213/6309), that would be:

```
sed 1d "${p_path}${csv_name}" | while IFS=, read -r gcm; do xml_nm xml_m co2con batchy; done
```